# Wordpress inline styles from Customizer in production

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am relatively new in web development. I have question more about best practices and common patterns.

I am using wordpress, I found free theme and using it like starting point to build web site. This theme provides possibility to configure it using `Customizer`, so you can just change values in interactive mode to apply settings.

And than this goes into header `inline css style` so all styles are stored directly in html and for sure they override styles defined in css files.

I found this feature useful for people who are not familiar with web design and development in depth, you can tune up web site just clicking buttons.

But personally for this inline code looks ugly in source code of the page, and to override it I need to inline directly inside `tag` using `style`. So I prefer modifying styles directly from css file.

All in all my question is : Is it good practice for using such customizers in production or it is better to structure all styles inside css files without ability to change appearance from customizer.

P.S I am going to use this site for personal purpose, so no one else will  modify it.

Answer (score 1):

Some themes offer a UI to edit background/text colors. If this is your case then I would just use that if it's all you need.

If you're actually writing custom styles then whenever possible I suggest creating a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for customizing 3rd party themes. This offers separation from site content (stored in the database) from code and it separates your custom code from the 3rd party's theme code. This option requires that you can upload your own themes.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but child theme is not a choice, because I need to modify a lot of code, so I think, I will end up with removing customizer from the theme completely.